# How to break an array after certain limit in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Following is my array that I need to break in parts, i.e to break into parts of 2 as shown below -

**Array to iterate -**

```
[
    {elem: 1},
    {elem: 2},
    {elem: 3},
    {elem: 4},
    {elem: 5},
    {elem: 6},
    {elem: 7},
    {elem: 8},
    {elem: 9}
]
```

**Desired Output -**

```
[
 {week1: [{elem: 1},{elem: 2}]},
 {week2: [{elem: 3},{elem: 4}]},
 {week3: [{elem: 5},{elem: 6}]},
 {week4: [{elem: 7},{elem: 8}]},
 {week5: [{elem: 9}]},
]
```

Following is the code I am trying but somehow breaking, let me know what I am doing wrong here -

**My Code -**

```
var myArr = [
    {elem: 1},
    {elem: 2},
    {elem: 3},
    {elem: 4},
    {elem: 5},
    {elem: 6},
    {elem: 7},
    {elem: 8},
    {elem: 9}
];

var arrayBreakNum = 2;
var newArr = [];
var weekNum = 1;

for(var i=1; i<= myArr.length; i++) {
    newArr.['week'+weekNum].push(myArr[i]);
    if(i%2 == 0)
        weekNum = weekNum + 1;
}

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things you need to change:

---

Theres a syntax error here:

```
newArr.['week'+weekNum].push(myArr[i]);
```

Change to:

```
newArr['week'+weekNum].push(myArr[i]);
```

---

You're trying to push to an array you haven't yet initialised here:

```
newArr.['week'+weekNum].push(myArr[i]);
```

Change to:

```
newArr['week'+weekNum] = [];
for(var i=1; i<= myArr.length; i++) {
    newArr['week'+weekNum].push(myArr[i]);
    if(i%2 == 0){
        weekNum = weekNum + 1;
        newArr['week'+weekNum] = [];
    }
}
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/6e6d3fuv/

Comment: almost working, you have element 1 in 5the array and not in first

Comment: @lordkain So does the OP :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var myArr = [
    {elem: 1},
    {elem: 2},
    {elem: 3},
    {elem: 4},
    {elem: 5},
    {elem: 6},
    {elem: 7},
    {elem: 8},
    {elem: 9}
];

var arrayBreakNum = 2;
var newArr = [];
var weekNum = 1;

for(var i=1; i<= myArr.length; i++) {
    //you need to create an empty array
    if(!newArr['week'+weekNum]) {
        newArr['week'+weekNum] = [];
    }

    newArr['week'+weekNum].push(myArr[i]); //you had an unessecary . in this line
    if(i%2 == 0) {
        weekNum = weekNum + 1;
    }
}

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: Thanks and +1 for the solution